# how to rotate 30 degree, every i click left mouse button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm new to Unity. I want to rotate a simple plane around the z axis. The problem is that when the plane rotates more than 360 degree, it does not rotate anymore.

This my code:

```
private float a;
private bool clicked = true;


void Update() {
    if(clicked)
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            StartCoroutine(rotasi ());
        }
    }
}
IEnumerator rotasi()
{   
    var a = transform.eulerAngles.z+30;     
    while(true)
    {
        if(transform.eulerAngles.z < a)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation,Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,0,a)),Time.deltaTime*30f);
            clicked = false;

            yield return null;
        }

        StartCoroutine(wait());
        yield return 0;
    }   
}
IEnumerator wait()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.2f);
    clicked = true;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `unity` tag for questions related to Unity game engine. There's `unity3d` tag for it.

Answer (score 0):

When you've hit 360 degrees or above, go back to 0 degrees.

0 degrees is effectively the same as 360 degrees but Unity may not support going 360 degrees or above.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are over 360 degrees. If yes, just subtract 360 from your endresult.

```
if (transform.eulerAngles.z + 30 >= 360)
    var a = transform.eulerAngles.z + 30 - 360
else
    var a = transform.eulerAngles.z + 30
```

This code could be smaller and more performing. But I think you get the idea.

Comment: a= (transform.eulerAngles.z + 30) % 360

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant with smaller and more performing code. But I wanted to make sure, that he gets the point.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same issue I was with continuous rotation, I was able to continually rotate a pentagon (hence the 72 degrees) with this:

```
    void Update()
    {
        if (Rotating)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Target, .075f);
            if (transform.rotation == Target)
            {
                Rotating = false;
                transform.rotation = Target;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Rotate()
    {
        if (Rotating)
        {
            return;
        }
        Target = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(72, 0, 0);
        Rotating = true;
    }
```